# How to apply bootstrap's table-responsive class for lager screen that are more than 767px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html-table

defaulty we know the bootstrap's `table-responsive` class is limited to the screens that are `lesser than 767px`. How can we apply bootstrap's `table-responsive` class for `lager screen that are more than 767px`.

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
        <th>Table heading</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Create a custom class?

Comment: @AndyHolmes Can I use the same class? Instead of creating a new one.

Comment: You can use the same class and add it to your CSS outside of a media query, or inside a media query with a larger max-width

Comment: @Tom actually I've tried to implement the same class using media queries but I failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use this class in your custom CSS :

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {  
.table-responsive {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
}
```

Comment: class is working if you increase your TD's check this link : http://codepen.io/inewton/pen/wzRqpj

Comment: thank you for your reply. It is working, but I don't want to wrap the text or content into new line (means word wrapping is happening in the code you provided to me).

Comment: if you want to avoid word break when you resize your window you must use this css th, td { white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;}  
source link : http://codepen.io/inewton/pen/wzRqpj  - @e-Designary

Comment: One small help, how can I fix (fixed header) the table header for this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBBqZO

Comment: for fixed header use { position: fixed; top: 0;} for first row and second row for {position: absolute; top: 30px;}

http://codepen.io/inewton/pen/ObWONX

Comment: Thank you, for your reply, here the header is fixed but the table cells and table headings are not corresponding to each other. I mean the width is not same for both